# Filetype that LaTeX should be

Tags: vimrc, filetype, filetype-tex

[From `:help filetype`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html):

> If the first line of a *.tex file has the form    `%&<format>` then this
>   determined the file type:  plaintex (for plain TeX), context (for
>   ConTeXt), or tex (for LaTeX).
>   Otherwise, the file is searched for keywords to choose context or tex.  If > no keywords are found, it
>   defaults to plaintex. 
>   You can change the default by defining the
>   variable `g:tex_flavor` to the format (not the file type) you use most. 
>   Use one of these:
>   `let g:tex_flavor = "plain"`
>   `let g:tex_flavor = "context"`
>   `let g:tex_flavor = "latex"`

If I open a file from the terminal using `vim t.tex` then run

```
:set ft?
```

It returns

```
filetype=plaintex
```

This should be `filetype=latex` shouldn't it?

If I open a previous document (that was written in TexMaker) within vim and run `:set ft?` it returns `filetype=tex`. hmm.

I have added `let g:tex_flavour = "latex"` to my vimrc, but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

I'm not sure what's best here, and what should be the prefered option. I appreciate that the question perhaps part LaTeX part Vim, but the issues I'm having aren't related to LaTeX afaik.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When there's not enough information to decide otherwise, `'filetype'` is set to the most basic -- `plaintex`.  Your existing file must have had enough content for the detection to determine that it was actually LaTeX, so `'filetype'` was set to `tex`.

The required command to prefer LaTex when there isn't enough information is

```
let g:tex_flavor = "latex"
```

Note, that's `flavor`, not `flavour`.

Comment: argh flavor flavour, whoops. cheers

Comment: You forgot the extra u in "cheers".  -cheerus.